# Creating a "read more" link that extends the content of the text

Tags: php

I would like to create link that outputs the full text in a stored variable:

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$text= "Sample text";

$string = strip_tags($text);

if (strlen($text) > 500) {

// truncate string
$stringCut = substr($text, 0, 500);

$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="#">Read More</a>'; 
}
echo $string;
?>
```

The problem arises in that the rest of the text past the word limit will not be shown when I attempt to click on the "read more" link. Any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

you have muliple choice to do that, if the your text is so long and containts images ...etc you can use ajax to call the server and get the full text and images ....etc, 
you can also just use javascript and css, hide the full text and when u click the link show it that's all.

```
<p id="intro">
    introlorem ......
    <a href="#" id="readmore">read more</a>
  </p>
  <p id="fulltext" style="display:none;">fulltext lorem ipsum ....</p>
  <script>
     $('#readmore').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#intro').hide();
        $('#fulltext').show();
     });
  </script>
```